# How do I construct permutations of string with str_replace across multiple arrays?

Tags: php

I'm trying to determine all possible combinations of an item code from multiple arrays of options.

```
$baseCode='S2BsizeR11reflectiveA';

$2BSizes=array('3030','3636','4848');
$reflective=array('3','H');
```

The end result should be an array of each possible combo.

```
$endResult=array('S3030R11HA','S3030R113A', 'S3636R11HA','S3636R113A','S4848R11HA','S4848R113A');
```

Comment: If you think my answer is useful, please upvote it ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested loop and a simple **str_replace**.

Doing this, it will act like a column/row pair.

First iteration

- 3030 / 3

Second iteration

- 3030 / H

Third iteration :

- 3036 / 3

And so on...

```
$baseCode='S2BsizeR11reflectiveA';

$BSizes=array('3030','3636','4848');
$reflective=array('3','H');

$result = [];
foreach ($BSizes as $size) {
  foreach ($reflective as $reflec) {
    $initial = ['2Bsize', 'reflective'];
    $replacing = [$size, $reflec];
    $result[] = str_replace($initial, $replacing, $baseCode);
  }
}
sort($result);
```

[image]

PS : be careful, **$2BSizes** is not a valid variable name (you can't add a number after a $)